# Why does Code Contracts produce a MyAssembly.Contracts.pdb file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, code-contracts

When setting "Contract Reference Assembly" to "Build" in the Code Contracts tab of the project properties, two additional files are created (for an assembly named "MyAssembly") in the "CodeContracts" subfolder of the output folder:

```
MyAssembly.Contracts.dll
MyAssembly.Contracts.pdb
```

The first file contains all contract metadata and I understand its uses. What I don't understand is why the second file, the .pdb, is created, and whether it is needed by consumers of contract metadata (e.g. Code Contracts itself in another solution, the Code Contracts Editor Extensions, etc).

If I want other consumers of the metadata to work correctly, do I need to include the .pdb as well, or is it completely unneeded?

Comment: You don't need it outside of debugging. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1.aspx.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of pdb files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582751/what-is-the-purpose-of-pdb-files)

Comment: @Igby: True, but since that assembly neither contains any code nor can even be run or debugged, what is the purpose of that PDB? Why is it even generated? And since the entire purpose of the contracts assembly is to provide metadata, which is exactly what a PDB contains, does it provide any useful metadata that the actual DLL doesn't?

Comment: @AllonGuralnek: It *might* be used if someone builds another assembly which references yours, and the `.Contracts.dll` is used as a contract reference assembly. You could try asking the CC people on their MSDN forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-nz/codecontracts/threads

Comment: @Porges: [Good idea](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/codecontracts/thread/a5e6f02e-4148-46b8-9cd9-67298bc6bcd5)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've posted this question in the Code Contracts MSDN Forum and got an answer from Manuel Fahndrich.

The static checker uses the generated pdb file to point to the contract that was violated in the source code (the PDB is used for IL -> source code mapping). This is only useful to whomever wrote the contract, since without the source code the contract pdb has little use, so there's no need to ship the `.Contracts.pdb` to third parties, only the `.Contracts.dll`.